# Exploring databased typing scheme at run time

Tags: caching, database-design, entity-framework-5, scaffolding

We have built a database in SQL Server using two patterns we found in Len Silverston's Data Model Resource Book Vol. 3, one for Types and Categories: Classification and another for Hierarchies, Aggregations, and Peer-to-Peer relationships.  Essentially, it is implmented as follows:

**Classification**

[Entity] (M x M) [EntityType] (M x M) [EntityTypeType]

...where the (M x M) is a many-to-many relationship implemented in the database by a Classification table.

**Association**

The entity and type tables above also have their own typed Rollups:

- [Entity] (M x M) [Entity]
- [EntityType] (M x M) [EntityType]
- [EntityTypeType] (M x M) [EntityTypeType]

...where each (M x M)  is a many-to-many relationship implemented in a Rollup table with a foreign key to the type of rollup/association.

The resulting data structure gives us tremendous expressive ability in terms of describing both our entities and their relationships to one another.  However, we're having trouble taking advantage of this expressiveness in our applications.  The primary issue is that in spite of the advances in EF 4& 5, M-2-M relationships are still tricky and beyond that we're trying to access the M-2-M's in at least 2 directions whenever we hit the database.  It is especially complicated by:

1. We subtype both [Entity] and some subtypes of [Entity].
2. All the of the M2M tables - all the classification and rollup/association tables - have a payload that contains at least a From and Thru date.  The rollups also contain at least a rollup type.
3. We don't want to have to load large, distant portions of the typing schema (EntityTypeType tables and their roll-ups) in order to interpret the data at runtime every time we access entities.

**Technologies**:

- SQL Server 2008 R2
- Entity Framework 5
- .NET 4.5
- MVC 4 (in the web app portion, we also have some Console Apps)

**Questions about the model itself:**

- Is this simply an unworkable data model in .NET?
- Should we first flatten our database into more .NET friendly views that essentially model our business objects?

**Questions about the typing scheme** - bear in mind that the types are pretty static:

- Should we scaffold the [EntityType] and [EntityTypeType] tables, their classifications, and their rollups into C# classes? This would work similar to enum scaffolders, only we need more than a name/int since these have payloads date range and type payloads.  If so, what are some ideas for how to scaffold those files - as static classes? Hard-coded object lists?
- Should we instead cache the typing scheme at start-up (this bothers me, because it adds a lot of overhead to starting up the Console Apps)?
- Any other ideas - scaffolded XML Files? etc...

Any ideas or experiences are much appreciated!

Comment: So are you trying to dynamically interpret the database at run-time? For example, let's say you have a User entity. User has 10 fields. You want to add an 11th field and not update the code? The code should dynamically see the 11th field and act accordingly? Same with relationships/etc.?

Comment: No, it's just that we have a complex typing scheme and want more or less the whole thing available at run time.  The database does not need to physically change.

Comment: The entity value design is the worst of all worlds if you knwo what fields you need. It is a poor prefromer and harder to query. I woudl redsiogn this database to use the realtional model correctly rather than this mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to answer each question, but I have to admit I'm not sure if you are trying to dynamically create entities on top of a database at run-time - or if you're just trying to create entities dynamically before run-time.

If you're trying to release code that dynamically changes/adjusts when the schema in SQL Server is changed, then I would have some different answers.  =)

> Is this simply an unworkable data model in .NET?

Some things you mentioned that stood out to me:

1. Lots of M x M relationships.
2. Entity/EntityType/EntityTypeType
3. Rollups

Some questions I have after reading:

1. Did you guys pick a framework for modeling data in the hopes it would make everything easier?
2. Did you pick a framework because it seemed like the "right" way to do it?
3. I have a hard time following how you've modeled the data. What is an EntityTypeType exactly?
4. Are all the M x M relationships really needed? Just because Entity A and Entity B can be in a M x M relationship, should they?

I don't know your domain, but I know I have a hard time following what you've described. =) In my opinion it has already become somewhat unworkable for two reasons: 1) You're asking on SO about it, b) It's not easy to describe without a lot of text.

> Should we first flatten our database into more .NET friendly views that essentially model our business objects?

Yes!

At least from my experience I would say yes. =)

I think it's ok to create entities in the database that have complex relationships. Parent/child, peer to peer, hierarchical, etc. All fine and good and normal.

But the application shouldn't have to interpret all of that to make sense of it. The database is good at doing joins, grouping data, creating views, etc. I would advise creating views or stored procedures that get as close to your business objects as possible - at least for the reads.

Also consider that if you push the complexity of relating objects to the application, you might pay some performance penalties.

> Should we scaffold the [EntityType] and [EntityTypeType] tables, their classifications, and their rollups into C# classes?

I would advise against this. The only reason is that now you are doing database work in the application layer. If you want to do joins/rollups/etc. you're managing that data in the application - not the database.

I'm sure you already know this, but you want to avoid bringing back everything in the database into the application and *then* running queries/building objects.

SQL Server is awesome at relating objects and pulling together different entities. It'll be very fast at that layer.

I would create business objects and populate those from SQL.

If you needed to scaffold EntityType/EntityTypeType, just be careful you aren't running into N+1 issues.

> What are some ideas for how to scaffold those files - as static classes? Hard-coded object lists?

Options:

1. Use an ORM to generate the classes for you. You've already seen some of that with EF.
2. Write your own code generation tool by looking at the SQL Server schemas for your entities.
3. Write classes by hand that aren't generated. I see this done all the time and it's not as bad as you think. Definitely some grunt work, but also gives flexibility.

> Should we instead cache the typing scheme at start-up (this bothers me, because it adds a lot of overhead to starting up the Console Apps)?

You want to generate the business objects based on your entities at application load? Or another way of phrasing the question ... generate proxy classes at runtime?

Comment: In answer to your questions: I do not want to change the schema at run time.  Our types for, say, paint.  Paint has a color, a luminosity, stickiness rating.  Each of these is type data for paint records.  Rather than create a column for each of each type, we create an MxM between paint and its types.  All of the types listed share the type of type - description or composition.  However, we could easily have that same paint categorized by marketing factors (industrial, cheap).  In some instances, these may overlap, say sheen is both a compositional and marketing type for paint.

Comment: Paint has *A* color, *A* luminosity and *A* stickiness. Those are three 1:N relationships, not a N:M relationship. A paint will never have two colors or more...

Comment: @Hazzit - only if the ways to describe paint remain static.  If we decide to track transparency, then durability, then ... we'd have to update the model each time.  Is this really preferable?

Comment: @fordareh: for the most part: yes. That is what a *model* is for: describing the relations of entities. Modeling a database without changing the model not only sounds wrong - more often than not it is a *Bad Idea(TM)*

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Len Silverston's book, and I assume neither is the vast majority of StackOverflow users. Since you didn't get answers to your question within 3 days, I'll now comment on it anyhow.

What strikes me as odd in your database model is that you seem to have multiple nested N:M relationships. There rarely ever are true N:M relationships - most of the time the intermediate table in a N:M relational model actually represents an object that exists in real life, leaving you with two regular 1:N relationships and more than just two columns in the linking table. I've only come across one or two true N:M relations in the last 25 years, so I kind of doubt you've actually got three here - it seems more likely that you're using a pattern that does not apply in the way you think it does.

What you describe smells a bit like you're trying to model a database in a database. Especially the "Should we first flatten our database into more .NET friendly views that essentially model our business objects?" sounds fishy. With very few exceptions, your database tables should match your business objects to begin with. If you need to create a flattened view to see your actual objects, you might be entirely heading in the wrong direction. But then again, its hard to tell from the information you gave.

Please give a less abstract description of what you're trying to do, what you've done so far.